# validating an array of uuids in nestjs swagger body

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, nestjs-swagger

It sounds like a quite simple question but I've been searching for a solution for a very long time now. I want to validate an array of UUIDs in an endpoint.

Like this:
`["9322c384-fd8e-4a13-80cd-1cbd1ef95ba8", "986dcaf4-c1ea-4218-b6b4-e4fd95a3c28e"]`

I have already successfully implemented it as a JSON object `{ "id": ["9322c384-fd8e-4a13-80cd-1cbd1ef95ba8", "986dcaf4-c1ea-4218-b6b4-e4fd95a3c28e"]}` with the following code:

```ts
public getIds(
  @Body(ValidationPipe)
  uuids: uuidDto
) {
  console.log(uuids);
}
```

```ts
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsUUID } from 'class-validator';

export class uuidDto {
  @IsUUID('4', { each: true })
  @ApiProperty({
    type: [String],
    example: [
      '9322c384-fd8e-4a13-80cd-1cbd1ef95ba8',
      '986dcaf4-c1ea-4218-b6b4-e4fd95a3c28e',
    ],
  })
  id!: string;
}
```

But unfortunately I can't customize the function that calls that endpoint. So I need a solution to only validate a array of uuids.

Answer (score 0):

instead of type string , write string[]. like below:

```ts
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsUUID } from 'class-validator';

export class uuidDto {
  @IsUUID('4', { each: true })
  @ApiProperty({
    type: string[],
    example: [
      '9322c384-fd8e-4a13-80cd-1cbd1ef95ba8',
      '986dcaf4-c1ea-4218-b6b4-e4fd95a3c28e',
    ],
  })
  id!: string[];
}
```

Comment: But then the problem is still, that I have an object with property id which is an array, I only wanna have an array without the need of the id property

Comment: So I guess the DTO approach is wrong, since I do not have an object

Comment: yes , you dont need an object but if you think you do , simply create an interface for it and export it then use it in your dto

Answer (score 0):

You can build a [custom validation pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#custom-pipes) for it:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomClassValidatorArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private classValidatorFunction: (any)) {}

  transform(value: any[], metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const errors = value.reduce((result, value, index) => {
      if (!this.classValidatorFunction(value))
        result.push(`${value} at index ${index} failed validation`)
      return result
    }, [])

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw new BadRequestException({
        status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        message: 'Validation failed',
        errors
      });
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

In your controller:

```js
@Post()
createExample(@Body(new CustomClassValidatorArrayPipe(isUUID)) body: string[]) {
  ...
}
```

- Ensure to use the **lowercase functions from class-validator**. It has to be `isUUID` instead of `IsUUID`. (This is used for the [manual validation with class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#manual-validation).)
- `CustomClassValidatorArrayPipe` is build modular. You can validate any other type with it. For example a `MongoId`: `@Body(new CustomClassValidatorArrayPipe(isMongoId)) body: ObjectId[]`

#### Result

If you send this:

```yaml
POST http://localhost:3000/example
Content-Type: application/json

[
  "986dcaf4-c1ea-4218-b6b4-e4fd95a3c28e",
  "123",
  "test"
]
```

Server will reply:

```json
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Validation failed",
  "errors": [
    "123 at index 1 failed validation",
    "test at index 2 failed validation"
  ]
}
```